# Apache Nifi - Split Array and format as JSON?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

Probably a simple beginners question:

Using NIFI, I want to split an array (represented flowfile-content) in the form of

```json
["x1","x2", ..]
```

and format it to a JSON object of the form

```json
{"key1":"x1", "key2":"x2", ..}
```

(also as flowfile-content)

What processor is the most efficent to be used, how would the expression script look like ?

Thanks in advance,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Applying **Jolt** transformations through use of a **JoltTransformJSON** processor might be a good choice. In which, you can add such a specification below by clicking on the ***ADVANCED*** button that's stated in the ***SETTINGS*** tab of ***Configure Processor*** dialog box :

```json
[
  //Determine respective lists to be used to calculate their sizes within the next step 
  //in order to get ordinals for the key values
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&(0,0).[#2]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=size(@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  //exchange key and values
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  },
  //add the desired word such as "key"
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "key&(0,0)"
    }
  }
]
```